# Create One-Dimensional array from evaluate

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

***Background:***

I'm trying to loop through a series of sheets in a workbook from an `Array` given certain sheets names.

***Code***

Instead of the more conventional:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
    Debug.Print ws.Name
Next ws

End Sub
```

I'm using a different method that makes it all a bit easier to extend the array to like 10 worksheets, or start at another number, like so:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arr As Variant: arr = ["Sheet"&ROW(1:3)]

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr)
    Debug.Print ws.Name
Next ws

End Sub
```

***Problem:***

However `["Sheet"&ROW(1:3)]` will create a two-dimensional array which will throw an `Error 13` on the start of the `For each...` loop because the array expects a one-dimensional array.

I can addres this problem using a simple `TRANSPOSE` like:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arr As Variant: arr = [TRANSPOSE("Sheet"&ROW(1:3))]

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr)
    Debug.Print ws.Name
Next ws

End Sub
```

***Question:***

Maybe my brain is tired but right now I fail to understand why `["Sheet"&ROW(1:3)]` would not create a one-dimensional array. Does anybody know?

I'm afraid the answer is simple, and I'll have one of those "Ahaaaa" moments.

Comment: `ROW(1:3)` is a range, a range is a two dimensional array of values.

Comment: To add onto Scott's comment, `Row(1:3)` is similar to `Range(Cells(1,"A"),Cells(3,"XFD"))`.

Comment: @ScottCraner, this is as easy as "ABC" and I feel stupid now, truely having a "Ahaaaa" moment =). Care to answer the question below?

Comment: @JvdV that question format looks nice... i swear i've seen it somewhere lol.  we all have those moments!

Comment: @Cyril, thanks, not sure where you would have seen it. I use this format (kind of the same all the time) when I do have a question.

Comment: @JvdV was making a bit of a joke as it matches all of my questions as well, and at one point i was discussing on meta about having a more standardized format for SO to help ensure that there was a space for each "background", "issue", "question", and "related code", where the final answer was that it might seem appropriate for SO but not all sites in SE, so not going to happen... every time I see a post well constructed in similar sections it just makes me smile a little.

Comment: @cyril, haven't seen but I am the same. A clear question can make for a clear answer. Unfortunately this one could have been avoided haha =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Short:

`ROW(1:3)` is a Range.  Ranges that contain more than one cell are two dimensional arrays.  Thus you get a two dimensional return.

Comment: I just want to point that you are 99,999999% right and I totally upvoted. Just want to add that if the range is just 1 single cell, then it's not two dimensional array. Even more, you can't take the value into an array with something like `Dim MyArray As Variant
 MyArray = Range("A1").Value`. This will not create an array, even if the object is a range one because it's a single cell.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns not at all, need to make it correct.  Do not want to mislead any future visitors.