# Retrieve one-dimensional array of values directly through Evaluate

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

***Background:***

In my [former](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58505728/9758194) question I set up how I retrieved a range of worksheets in an array in order to loop through them.

I would like to take it a step further and instead retrieve an array of values, e.g.: `{"Val1", "Val2", "Val3"}`

***Code:***

To work with the following codes, you could replicate what I'm trying to achieve with creating a bunch of sheets, named "Sheet1", "Sheet2" etc etc. Then input a module:

```
Sub Test

Dim lwr As Long: lwr = 2
Dim uppr As Long: uppr = 5

'Options will follow here *

End sub
```

This is how I would retrieve the worksheet array with dynamic row variables. You will see it will pull an array of sheetnames that we could use in for example: `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shts)`:

```
Dim shts As Variant: shts = Application.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(""Sheet""&ROW(" & lwr & ":" & uppr & "))")
```

Now however, I would like to take an array of values directly from these sheets. This is how I would retrieve the cells I'm interested in (the same cell across all sheets), e.g. `A1`:

```
Dim shts As Variant: shts = Application.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(""Sheet""&ROW(" & lwr & ":" & uppr & ")&""!A1"")")
```

The cells references are rather pointless, but one example this would work with is when all values would be numeric and I want to be able to sum like this:

```
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("SUM(" & Join(shts, ",") & ")")
```

However I would like to pull them into an array variable directly (without a loop through sheets), no matter numeric or non-numeric, e.g: `{5,3,"Val1",6}`

***Problem:***

I've tried several things amongst `INDIRECT`, `VALUE`, and even `ADDRESS` to put the range into a named range first. All attempts are futile since none of these functions seem to work with arrays. For example:

```
Dim vals As Variant: vals = Application.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(""Sheet""&ROW(" & lwr & ":" & uppr & ")&""!A1""))")
```

Will throw an array with a bunch of errors as the problem most likely lays with non-contiguous ranges.

***Question:***

Any way to retrieve an one-dimensional array succesfully directly through evaluation? Or is what I'm seeking simply not possible, which in that case brings me back to a loop to get my array.

Comment: This is probably not in the least bit helpful, but have you considered INDEX? I only mention because I had this in mind https://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/758402-vba-working-with-areas-within-2d-arrays.html

Comment: @Sjr thanks for the link, I have been tinkering around with Index as well though without success so far. Obviously will inform when I do manage to find something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually using `CHOOSE` in the `.Evaluate` did it for me:

```
Dim lwr As Long: lwr = 2
Dim uppr As Long: uppr = 5

Dim shts As Variant: shts = Application.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(""Sheet""&ROW(" & lwr & ":" & uppr & ")&""!A1"")")
Dim vals As Variant: vals = Application.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(CHOOSE(ROW(1:" & uppr - lwr + 1 & ")," & Join(shts, ",") & "))")
```

What I did here:

- Get a lower bound > `lwr`
- Get a upper bound > `uppr`
- Get an array of ranges through `.Evaluate` with those bounds
- Get an array of values through `Join` of the previous array within an `.Evaluate` that makes use of `CHOOSE`.

If for example `Sheet2!A1` = `4`, `Sheet3!A1` = `5`, `Sheet4!A1` = `1`, `Sheet5!A1` = `Test`

The above code will then return the following for `vals`:

[image]

As you can see, it holds a one-dimensional array with variant values. Exactly what I wanted. I'm now able to get a dynamic array pulling values from different sheets in one go.

Comment: Nice work, wonder what put you on to CHOOSE. Next steps - non-consecutive sheets, different cells? An intellectual exercise or for something specific?

Comment: Yes next step is non consecutive sheets, and it's all really an intellectual exercise @SJR, I am always telling people to use arrays so I was wondering how else I could get arrays quickly and can't recall I have seen something like this before. There always was a loop involved. So I started of with the dynamic sheets array, then this. `CHOOSE` came into the picture when I was thinking which functions would take non consecutive cells. On to non-consecutive sheets now....=). Thanks