# Count IF on multiple sheets, VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
If Application.CountIf(Sheet5.Range("A:A"), TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then
 GoTo 10
Else....
```

This code checks if there is already a value from Textbox1 somewhere in A column(a list of values).

Now I want to transform the code so it checks existence of a value(from textbox1) in multiple sheets(growing), but only in one cell from every sheet(say: A1).
Can this be done with count if somehow? I dont want to use Loops (for, with..) takes to long on few hundreds of sheets

Comment: *I dont want to use Loops* Then there is no way you can achieve what you want. Consider using a different approach

Comment: Consider limiting the range for the `COUNTIF`  a single column may be 1,048,576 rows   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Answer (score 0):

See the below:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    formula = formula & "," & ws.Name & "!A1"
Next ws

formula = "=COUNTIF({" & Mid(formula, 2) & "}, TextBox1.Value)"

If Application.Evaluate(formula) = 0 Then
    GoTo 10
Else....
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looping (and the use of ms365's [`TOCOL()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/tocol-function-22839d9b-0b55-4fc1-b4e6-2761f8f122ed)), you could use [3D-referencing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-c906f8b4-c648-4aa0-8063-65d38d03370f). But make sure your range of worksheets are connected. For example:

```
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("SUM(N(TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet100!A1,3)=" & TextBox1.Value & "))")
```

This is very much so like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58524525/9758194) older post, but `TOCOL()` makes life easier, plus you won't run into the limits of the [`Evaluate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) method.

---

Note that if you have a growing number of sheets, you could also opt for:

```
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("SUM(N(TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet" & Application.Sheets.Count & "!A1,3)=" & TextBox1.Value & "))")
```